# Class declared but not exist yet

Tags: php, class, abstract-class

I have few files in same folder:

test.php:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
}
$b = new B();
echo 'done' . PHP_EOL;
```

A.php:

```
echo 'include A' . PHP_EOL;
abstract class A {
    function __construct() {
    }
}
require_once ('A.php');
require_once ('B.php');
require_once ('C.php');

echo 'A exists - ' . (class_exists('A') ? 'yes' : 'no') . PHP_EOL;
echo 'B exists - ' . (class_exists('B') ? 'yes' : 'no') . PHP_EOL;
echo 'C exists - ' . (class_exists('C') ? 'yes' : 'no') . PHP_EOL;
```

B.php:

```
echo 'include B' . PHP_EOL;
final class B extends A {
}
```

C.php

```
echo 'include C' . PHP_EOL;
final class C extends A {
}
```

Result if I run test.php:

```
include B
include A
include C
A exists - yes
B exists - no
C exists - yes
done
```

**Why class B does not exists yet?**

Is it because it's inside of declaration code?

It's easy to fix just add include 'A.php'; first line in test.php.

Comment: Is this really yoru C.php? `echo 'include B' . PHP_EOL;
final class B extends A {
}`.... and why are you `require`ing files in A.php that your autoloader should be loading automatically?

Comment: Jason McCreary, It's working well. Why it's should be fatal error?

Comment: But class `B` won't exist until `A` has been defined (because it needs A to extend it) by including `A.php`; but all your class exists tests are executed in `A.php`, so before `B` has been fully defined..... do your class exists tests in `test.php`, and you should find that B has been fully defined by then

Comment: This is a simplified example on what a plugin that works on some machines but not others is doing.